# Listed as spam when trying to ask a question

Tags: support, asking-questions

I got this message when trying to post a question:

> Body cannot contain "".
>
> This appears to be spam. If you feel you've received this message in error, please visit meta.

Any help is appreciated.

The question:

---

Hello everyone,
I struggle with the following problem, which I hope can be solved elegantly in either Excel or R. I have a txt file which contains bibliographical information to 50 different articles. There are in total 100 of them, so manual labour would be very consuming.

What I would need in the end would be an excel file in which there is one header line, to be followed by 50 rows in which each row corresponds to one article. I have only found a way to do that with one reference. I would thus use the text to column function, using a : as a delimiter. Then, manually, I'd merge the keywords columns and delete the excess. But since there are more than 5000 articles, I hope there is a better way to do so. I have never worked with Makros thought, but understand a little bit of R... Any help appreciated!

```
{Reference Type}: Journal Article
{Title}: 体育文化软实力研究进展及提升策略
{Author}: 赵薇
{Author}: 王润平
{Author Address}: 西北师范大学体育学院;
{Journal}: 当代教育与文化
{Year}: 2017
{Issue}: 04
{Keywords}: 体育文化
{Keywords}: 软实力
{Keywords}: 研究进展
{Keywords}: 提升策略
{Abstract}: 世界各国都很重视体育文化软实力建设。我国体育文化软实力与欧美国家相较有一定的差距,中国现在的经济地位是全球第二,但文化地位却远远不能与经济地位相匹配,因此提升国家文化软实力就显得迫在眉睫。体育文化软实力包涵隐蔽性与易接受性、传统性与时代性、渗透性与持久性,据此提出了我国体育文化软实力建设,需加大体育文化产业的建设和创新力度,增加体育人口,提高大众体育文化生活满意度,发挥体育文化外交作用,注重体育文化教育等提升策略。
{ISBN/ISSN}: 1674-5779


{Reference Type}: Journal Article
{Title}: 一带一路建设中香港的新角色——基于软实力视角
{Author}: 李芝兰
{Author}: 梁雨晴
{Author Address}: 香港城市大学;深圳大学;
{Journal}: 开放导报
{Year}: 2017
{Issue}: 04
{Keywords}: 一带一路
{Keywords}: 软实力
{Keywords}: 香港
{Keywords}: 制度
{Keywords}: 专业服务
{Abstract}: 在一带一路实践中,提升国家软实力的重要性日渐明显。我国经济快速发展,但在软实力方面,与一些发达地区的差距依然存在。本文提出,香港拥有较为成熟的社会管理模式、优质的教育和科研资源,可通过构建适应一带一路的国际法框架、建立具公信力的新评级体系等金融和会计专业服务,直接服务于内地"走出去"的企业。
{ISBN/ISSN}: 1004-6623
```

Comment: I was sure it's this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356006/can-not-post-question-content-with-may-be-duplicate-but-that-question-do) but it isn't - But it look like it's the same issue

Answer (score 18):

The filter is *likely* reacting to the large amount of Unicode that it sees that isn't English, which is just your test data, which is more likely a false positive on that front.

However, I'm really not seeing how this question *should* be posted anyway.

Here's what your question is, emphasis mine:

> Hello everyone, I struggle with the following problem, which I hope
>   can be solved elegantly in either Excel or R. I have a txt file which
>   contains bibliographical information to 50 different articles. There
>   are in total 100 of them, so manual labour would be very consuming.
>
> **What I would need in the end would be an excel file** in which there is
>   one header line, to be followed by 50 rows in which each row
>   corresponds to one article. I have only found a way to do that with
>   one reference. I would thus use the text to column function, using a :
>   as a delimiter. Then, manually, I'd merge the keywords columns and
>   delete the excess. But since there are more than 5000 articles, I hope
>   there is a better way to do so. I have never worked with Makros
>   thought, but understand a little bit of R... Any help appreciated!

You're not asking a question that's looking for help with existing code. You *appear* to be asking us to write your code *for* you.  At best, that'll get downvoted and closed.  At worst, that'll set you up for a long question ban.

I would ***strongly*** encourage you not to post this question as-is.  Include what you've tried and where it's failing to meet your requirements instead of giving us your requirements.

Comment: Thanks Makoto, and particularly for your recommendation. I struggle a lot with getting into the right direction as I have only started working with code in the last few weeks and oftentimes do not know how to actually frame questions so that a google search would point me into a good direction. I will try to do better! Best regards!

Comment: This is correct. Your proposed post is not spam, but it is not suitable for this site and would likely be downvoted and closed for non-spam reasons. Having your question downvoted and closed for broadness and topic reasons is better than it being handled as Spam (or Rude), but this is like choosing whether you want to be shot with an AK-47 or a P90. Ideally you would want to not be shot at all.